# How to send a method pointer as a window message parameter?

Tags: delphi, function-pointers, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to call a method that is sent as a parameter through a window message. I tried as in the example below... but I get access violation when the `DoWork` method is executed. I think the procedural `CallBack` variable is not reconstructed properly in the message handler. In [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Procedural_Types_(Delphi)) it says that a "method pointer" variable has 2 pointers: "*These types represent method pointers. A method pointer is really a pair of pointers; the first stores the address of a method, and the second stores a reference to the object the method belongs to.*"... But I don't know how to access the second pointer, and then reconstruct the variable with those two pointers...

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TCallBackNotify = function(CallBack: Pointer = nil): Boolean of object;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure Test(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_USER;
    function DoWork(CallBack: Pointer = nil): Boolean;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Test(var Msg: TMessage);
var CallBack: TCallBackNotify;
begin
 if Msg.Msg = WM_USER then begin
  @CallBack:= Pointer(Msg.WParam);
  CallBack;
 end;
end;

function TForm1.DoWork(CallBack: Pointer = nil): Boolean;
begin
 Caption:= 'It''s working !';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var CallBack: TCallBackNotify;
begin
 CallBack:= DoWork;
 PostMessage(Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@CallBack) , 0);
end;

end.
```

Comment: So to answer part of your question, if `M` is any method pointer, then its two pointers are `TMethod(M).Data` and `TMethod(M).Code`.

Comment: Wow, that's it ! It's working now ! :) I wasn't aware of TMethod existence ! Thank you so much ! Post it as an answer so I can accept it...

Comment: It's easier to call TThread.Queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I don't know how to access the second pointer, and then reconstruct the variable with those two pointers...

From the documentation on [internal data formats](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Procedural_Types):

> A method pointer is stored as a 32-bit pointer to the entry point of a method, followed by a 32-bit pointer to an object.

in a 32-bit app. For a 64-bit app, the same applies, but with 64-bit pointers, of course.

This is actually all you need to know to access these pointers using pointer arithmetic, but it is much nicer to use the predefined [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) record:

If `M` is any method pointer, then `TMethod(M).Code` is the code (procedure) pointer and `TMethod(M).Data` is the data (object) pointer.

If you want to send or post a method pointer, you can either utilize LPARAM and WPARAM for these two pointers, or you can send a single pointer to a single record (or object) containing both. Just remember that when *posting* a message, you cannot pass the address of a local variable, since that one might go out of scope before it is received by the recipient.

---

When you write

```pascal
var
  CallBack: TCallBackNotify;
begin
  CallBack := DoWork;
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@CallBack) , 0);
```

you are sending `@CallBack`. Since `CallBack` is declared as a method pointer, `@CallBack` is the code pointer, i.e. `@CallBack = TMethod(CallBack).Code`. Hence, the data pointer isn't sent at all.

As a comparison, `@@CallBack` is the address of the local `CallBack` variable. If you had instead declared `CallBack` as a `TMethod` (a normal record), this address would have been denoted `@CallBack` only.

To illustrate this,

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CallBack: TCallBackNotify;
  CallBackRec: TMethod absolute CallBack;
begin
  CallBack := DoWork;
  ShowMessage(
    'Data = ' + NativeInt(CallBackRec.Data).ToString + #13#10 +
    ' = Self = ' + NativeInt(Self).ToString + #13#10 +
    'Code = ' + NativeInt(CallBackRec.Code).ToString + #13#10 +
    ' = @CallBack = ' + NativeInt(@CallBack).ToString + #13#10 +
    '@@CallBack = ' + NativeInt(@@CallBack).ToString + #13#10 +
    ' = @CallBackRec = ' + NativeInt(@CallBackRec).ToString + #13#10
  );
end;
```

may yield

```
Data            = 17376288
 = Self         = 17376288
Code            = 6278088
 = @CallBack    = 6278088
@@CallBack      = 1635636
 = @CallBackRec = 1635636
```

So, to *send* a method, you may do, for instance,

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CallBack: TCallBackNotify;
begin
  CallBack := DoWork;
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_USER, WParam(@@CallBack), 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Test(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  CallBack: TCallBackNotify;
begin
  if Msg.Msg = WM_USER then
  begin
    CallBack := TCallBackNotify(PMethod(Msg.WParam)^);
    CallBack;
  end;
end;
```

Since `SendMessage` is synchronous, it will not return until the message has been processed by the receiver; in particular, `SendMessage` will not return before `TForm1.Test` returns. Hence the `CallBack` local variable will be alive during this processing, so it is perfectly safe to use a pointer to this variable during this time.

On the other hand, if you instead *post* the message using `PostMessage`, which returns immediately, you will crash if you are lucky and potentially cause memory corruption otherwise. Indeed, then `Button1Click` will reach its `end`, the `CallBack` local variable will be discarded, and only later will `TForm1.Test` run -- being given a dangling pointer.